# Explaining the result of an if loop in python

Tags: python, while-loop

I have a question regarding the following python code. Please note that I'm a beginner in python and trying to learn procedural programming and algorithms on my own.

```
alpha = 5
if alpha > 2:
    print alpha
    alpha -= 1
    print alpha
```

Whilst I was previously expecting the answer to 5, 4, 3, I now understand why its 5, 4.

Comment: `if` **loop** ? Sure ?

Comment: I'm guessing this is a while loop then? I apologise for my ignorance here. I've removed "if" from the title to avoid the confusion.

Comment: As a beginner, you might want to spend some time reading [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: @das-g, thanks. I'm sure this is a very good reference as I learn more python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you want:

```
alpha = 5
while alpha > 2:
    print alpha   # <-- these 2 lines of code will be executed repeatedly
    alpha -= 1    # <-- as long as alpha is > to 2
```

This will print:

```
5
4
3
```

An if statement will test the conditions of entry once, execute the code inside and exit.

A while loop will check the condition on entry, and execute the code **while** the conditions are true, then exit the moment the condition is false.

The second print alpha became redundant in a while loop.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My main question is why is the output of the above code 5 and 4 rather than 5, 4 and 3? I'm pretty sure the above code is correct. I'm just not sure why the result is what it is.

Comment: And also the output for your code (5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2) is different from the one posted (5, 4).

Comment: @John Wait what? You just metioned three outputs: `(5, 4)`, `(5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2)` and `(5, 4, 3)`? One code can't produce three outputs.

Comment: It is because the original post was amended to reflect the real question Markus - originally it was an if block, not a while loop.

Comment: Sry, I originally posted an if statement and someone changed it to while loop-I've edited it.

Comment: there is no such thing as an "if loop", you are confused.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque, thanks. As I said in my question, I'm a beginner in python. Perhaps an if statement is more appropriate.

Comment: No worries, we've all been there. Are you satisfied with the answer John?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque: Sure, there's no such thing as an `if` loop. But you can't edit a mistake like that out of a question because it _radically_ changes the original author's intent.

Comment: I understand, that looked like a good idea at that moment PM 2Ring, my mistake :)

Comment: Not a problem. And I guess the title should be restored to its original state too.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque, I'd like to accept your answer but it doesn't produce the same output as my original code (note that my original code is an if statement).

Comment: I thought you wanted 5, 4, 3 output John --- > What exactly do you want?

Comment: @John: As Reblochon says in his answer, the code inside an `if` block is executed once if the condition is true. So if you want to loop while a condition is true you need to use a `while` block.

Comment: @PM2Ring, I get it now. Thanks.